# Saving multiple checkbox options

Tags: php, checkbox

I have this code here that saves only one checkbox selection in Wordpress.  How can I get it to save multiple values?  And if I'm storing values improperly (which I probably am), how can I post those correctly into the database?

Here is how I'm currently posting options:

```
   if (isset ($_POST['update_blog_options'])) {
     $montage_blog_options = get_option ('blog_settings');
     $montage_blog_options['user_cats'] = $_POST['user_cats'];
    update_option('blog_settings', $montage_blog_options);
    }
```

Then my code for creating checkbox array:

```
               $args = array( 'hide_empty' => 0, 'taxonomy'=> 'category');
               $categories =  get_categories($args);
               if ($categories){
                    foreach ( $categories as $category ){ 
                        if($category->cat_name==$montage_blog_options['user_cats']) {
                            $selected = 'checked="checked"';
                        } else {
                            $selected = '';
                        }

                        echo '<input name="user_cats" value="'.$category->cat_name.'" '.$selected.' type="checkbox"/> '.$category->cat_name.'<br/>';
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the name of the input to include a [] in the name, i.e. name="user_cats[]" then it will store all the instance of it as an array. then you can access the values as an array.

I can't remember exactly what it looks like when its gets to the page, but you can print_r($_POST['user_cats']) on receiving page to see what it looks like.

Comment: Hi Syndrose, I changed it but now it's not saving any options at all, when previously it was saving one option.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok...when I check multiple checkboxes, the array is producing those results, so the options are saving....it must be in the condition I'm using to show 'checked="checked"'

Comment: if it is coming over as an array, then you have to check to see if the value is in the array, you can do that with the in_array function.

Comment: yep, that was it - this function was originally there before, but I was using something completely different with in_array().  I will vote you answer.  Should we provide a more useful answer?  Here's the condition that worked  if( in_array ($category->cat_name, $montage_blog_options['user_cats'])) {
                                $selected = 'checked="checked"';
                            } else {
                                $selected = '';
                            }

Comment: Either way your answer helped.  I will check the answer and you can update if you want to make it more official for future viewers.